# Solving an Equation involving Factorials and Exponents.

Tags: combinatorics

Is it possible to find the value of $n$ in:

$$\Large{\frac { (_{ 365 }{ P }_{ n }) }{ { \left( 365 \right)  }^{ n } } \quad \approx \quad \frac { 1 }{ 5 }}$$

Please help! Thanks for your answers in advance!

Comment: Actually, I have problems finding *anything* in there

Comment: Sorry for that, I've fixed the problem. Thanks for considering though. Please see the question again.

Comment: Assuming $P_n$ denotes the factorial (as announced in the title?) there is no solution, as $\frac{1}{5}$ is not a power of 365.

Comment: Does $_{365}P_n$ mean $\frac{365!}{(365-n)!}$?

Comment: Yes @MarioG, It does.

Comment: Numerically, with $n = 34$ we'll get $0.2047\ldots$

Answer (score 1):

Ghastly notation...

You mean:
$$
\frac{365^{\underline{n}}}{356^n}
  = \frac{1}{5}
$$
where the *falling factorial power* is defined as:
$$
u^{\underline{k}} = u \cdot (u - 1) \cdot \ldots \cdot (u - k + 1)
$$
Seen this way, you are looking for:
$$
1 \cdot \left(1 - \frac{1}{365}\right)
  \cdot \ldots 
  \cdot \left(1 - \frac{n - 1}{365}\right)
 = \frac{1}{5}
$$
Obvious next step is a logarithm, and if $n$ is small enough so you can get away with the approximation:
$$
\ln (1 - x) = - x - \frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^3}{3} - \ldots \approx -x
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{365} + \ldots + \frac{n - 1}{365} 
  &\approx \ln 5 \\
\frac{1}{365} \sum_{1 \le k \le n - 1} k
  &= \frac{n (n - 1)}{365 \cdot 2}
\end{align}
This tells you that roughly:
$$
n \approx \sqrt{2 \cdot 365 \ln 5} = 33.85
$$
It turns out that $n = 34$ gives $0.1856$, while for $n = 33$ you get $0.2047$. Pretty close, considering the crude approximations used.

Comment: Don't you want to choose $n$ so that you get $1/5 = 0.2$?  Also, $\sum_{k = 1}^{n-1} k = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$: you appear to have forgotten the $2$ in the denominator.

Comment: @SpamIAm, I noticed by brain slip while you were commenting. Thanks!

Comment: @vonbrand: Thanks a ton! I am not good at maths, and have recently started taking interest in it. Sorry for my mistakes. Thanks a lot for help! I really needed the answer!